# Finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe in pandas that apart from the column used as index is supposed to have only numeric values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 'bad', 5],
                   'b': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
                   'item': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df = df.set_index('item')
```

How can I find the row of the dataframe `df` that has a non-numeric value in it?

In this example it's the fourth row in the dataframe, which has the string `'bad'` in the `a` column. How can this row be found programmatically?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You could use [`np.isreal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) to check the type of each element ([applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) applies a function to each element in the DataFrame):

```
In [11]: df.applymap(np.isreal)
Out[11]:
          a     b
item
a      True  True
b      True  True
c      True  True
d     False  True
e      True  True
```

If all in the row are True then they are all numeric:

```
In [12]: df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)
Out[12]:
item
a        True
b        True
c        True
d       False
e        True
dtype: bool
```

So to get the subDataFrame of rouges,  (Note: the negation, ~,  of the above finds the ones which have at least one rogue non-numeric):

```
In [13]: df[~df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)]
Out[13]:
        a    b
item
d     bad  0.4
```

You could also find the location of the *first* offender you could use [argmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
In [14]: np.argmin(df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1))
Out[14]: 'd'
```

As [@CTZhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487184/ct-zhu) points out, it may be slightly faster to [check whether it's an instance of](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) either int or float (there is some additional overhead with np.isreal):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))
```

Comment: Great! Only that `df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))` will be about 18% faster. Using `lambda` with build in method is sometimes reasonably fast.

Comment: @CTZhu Good point. I guess that's not soo suprising (since np.isreal does some other stuff too e.g. dealing with arrays not just single values).

Comment: don't forget that if you have an field (like a date or groupname) you'll want to do this only on that subset of columns of the dataframe

Comment: It's worth noting that `np.isreal(None) is not True`

Comment: How would you only check one column for values that aren't numbers?

Comment: @Superdooperhero use .apply on the column rather than .applymap on the DataFrame, i.e. `df["a"].apply(np.isreal)` and `df[~df["a"].apply(np.isreal)]`

Comment: 1) carefull: np.isreal will convert 'str' to False 
   a=pd.Series(['1', 2, 3, 'bad', 5]) ->  False, True, True, False, True  
2) carefull: a.str.isnumeric() will convert 'num' to NaN 
    a  -> True, NaN, NaN, False, NaN  
3) if Series/Column use a.apply(np.isreal) (.applymap will not work)

Answer (score 30):

Already some great answers to this question, however here is a nice snippet that I use regularly to drop rows if they have non-numeric values on some columns:

```
# Eliminate invalid data from dataframe (see Example below for more context)

num_df = (df.drop(data_columns, axis=1)
         .join(df[data_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')))

num_df = num_df[num_df[data_columns].notnull().all(axis=1)]
```

The way this works is we first `drop` all the `data_columns` from the `df`, and then use a `join` to put them back in after passing them through `pd.to_numeric` (with option `'coerce'`, such that all non-numeric entries are converted to `NaN`).   The result is saved to `num_df`.

On the second line we use a filter that keeps only rows where all values are not null.

Note that `pd.to_numeric` is coercing to `NaN` everything that cannot be converted to a numeric value, so strings that represent numeric values will not be removed. For example `'1.25'` will be recognized as the numeric value `1.25`.

Disclaimer: `pd.to_numeric` was introduced in pandas version `0.17.0`

**Example:**

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"item": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
   ...:                    "a": [1,2,3,"bad",5],
   ...:                    "b":[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
     a    b item
0    1  0.1    a
1    2  0.2    b
2    3  0.3    c
3  bad  0.4    d
4    5  0.5    e

In [4]: data_columns = ['a', 'b']

In [5]: num_df = (df
   ...:           .drop(data_columns, axis=1)
   ...:           .join(df[data_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')))

In [6]: num_df
Out[6]: 
  item   a    b
0    a   1  0.1
1    b   2  0.2
2    c   3  0.3
3    d NaN  0.4
4    e   5  0.5

In [7]: num_df[num_df[data_columns].notnull().all(axis=1)]
Out[7]: 
  item  a    b
0    a  1  0.1
1    b  2  0.2
2    c  3  0.3
4    e  5  0.5
```

Comment: This is what I use, for some reason top answer doesn't always work for me and ```convert_object``` is deprecated

Comment: I do something similar, but like this

float_cols=['a','b','c']      

for cols in float_cols:       
    df[cols]=df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)

This is particular to cases where I want the nan's to be zero, not nan. You could also leave out the fillna(0) bit.

Comment: Does this drop/join logic scale to millions of rows?

Answer (score 14):

```
# Original code
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 'bad', 5],
                   'b': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
                   'item': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df = df.set_index('item')
```

[Convert to numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) using 'coerce' which fills bad values with 'nan'

```
a = pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce')
```

Use [isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to return a boolean index:

```
idx = a.isna()
```

Apply that index to the data frame:

```
df[idx]
```

### output

Returns the row with the bad data in it:

```
        a    b
item          
d     bad  0.4
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about the confusion, this should be the correct approach. Do you want only to capture `'bad'` only, not things like `'good'`; Or just any non-numerical values?

```
In[15]:
np.where(np.any(np.isnan(df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)), axis=1))
Out[15]:
(array([3]),)
```

Comment: This will pick up `'bad'`, but won't pick up a rogue string number, though, because the conversion will succeed..

Comment: Or get into problems with coded strings representing valid numbers, like `'over_the_chart'`, representing the maximum allowed value for that variable. Probably not a safe way. I would rather approach the problem from the way to build the `dataframe` in the real world  case.

Comment: This depends whether you consider "4" bad or not, my gut feeling would be yes :S

Comment: ```convert_objects``` is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking something like, just give an idea, to convert the column to string, and work with string is easier. however this does not work with strings containing numbers, like `bad123`. and `~` is taking the complement of selection.

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)
df[~df['a'].str.contains('0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9')]
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(object)
```

and using `'|'.join([str(i) for i in range(10)])` to generate `'0|1|...|8|9'`

or using `np.isreal()` function, just like the most voted answer

```py
df[~df['a'].apply(lambda x: np.isreal(x))]
```

Comment: Please explain your solution

Comment: @BookOfZeus just convert it to string, and work with it. convert it back afterward.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are working with a column with string values, you can use
THE VERY USEFUL function series.str.isnumeric() like:

```
a = pd.Series(['hi','hola','2.31','288','312','1312', '0,21', '0.23'])
```

What i do is to copy that column to new column, and do a str.replace('.','') and str.replace(',','') then i select the numeric values.
and:

```
a = a.str.replace('.','')
a = a.str.replace(',','') 
a.str.isnumeric()
```

Out[15]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool

Good luck all!

Comment: why `2.31` is not numeric?

Comment: I think it is because it has a dot. What i do is to copy that column to new column, and do a str.replace('.','') and then i select the numeric values. I have recently faced that problem.

Comment: @toto_tico it is because of a dot. as per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html it "Check whether all characters in each string in the Series/Index are numeric"

Comment: @kekert, thanks, I forgot that, and there is actually no `isreal` (or similar) in str... @fra44, I think you should add the `str.replace` clarification directly in the answer because it can be missleading as it is...

Answer (score -1):

#### Did you convert your data using .astype() ?

All great comments above must solve 99% of the cases, but if you are still in trouble, please also check if you converted your data type.

Sometimes I force the data to type float16 to save memory. Using:

```
df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float16)
```

But this might silently break your code. So if you did any kind of data type transformation, double check for *overflows*. Disable the conversion and try again.

It worked for me!