# get non numerical rows in a column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I checked this post: [finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771133/finding-non-numeric-rows-in-dataframe-in-pandas) 
but it doesn't really answer my question.

my sample data:

```
import pandas as pd


d = {
 'unit': ['UD', 'UD', 'UD', 'UD', 'UD','UD'],
 'N-D': [ 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5','Q6'],
 'num' : [ -1.48, 1.7, -6.18, 0.25, 'sum(d)', 0.25]

}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

it looks like this:

```
  N-D   num   unit
0  Q1  -1.48   UD
1  Q2   1.70   UD
2  Q3  -6.18   UD
3  Q4   0.25   UD
4  Q5   sum(d) UD
5  Q6   0.25   UD
```

I want to filter out only the rows in column 'num' that are NON-NUMERIC. I want all of the columns for only the rows that contain non-numeric values for column 'num'.

desired output:

```
  N-D   num   unit
4  Q5   sum(d) UD
```

my attempts:

```
nonnumeric=df[~df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)] #didn't work, it pulled out everything, besides i want the condition to check only column 'num'. 

nonnumeric=df['num'][~df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)] #didn't work, it pulled out all the rows for column 'num' only.
```

Comment: non_num_rows = list(df[pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce').isnull()].index)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html)
Note: This solution does not find or filter numbers saved as strings: like '1' or '22'

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce'))
0   -1.48
1    1.70
2   -6.18
3    0.25
4     NaN
5    0.25
Name: num, dtype: float64

print (pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce').isnull())
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: num, dtype: bool

print (df[pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
  N-D     num unit
4  Q5  sum(d)   UD
```

Another solution with `isinstance` and `apply`:

```
print (df[df['num'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))])
  N-D     num unit
4  Q5  sum(d)   UD
```

Answer (score 14):

Old topic, but if the numbers have been converted to 'str', **type(x) == str**  is not working.

Instead, it's better to use isnumeric() or isdigit().

```
df = df[df['num'].apply(lambda x: not x.isnumeric())]
```

I tested all three approaches on my own dataframe with 200k+ rows, assuming numbers have been converted to 'str' by pd.read_csv().

```
def f1():
    df[pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce').isnull()]

def f2():
    df[~df.num.str.match('^\-?(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)$')]

def f3():
    df[df['num'].apply(lambda x: not x.isnumeric())]
```

I got following execution times by running each function 10 times.

```
timeit.timeit(f1, number=10)
1.04128568888882

timeit.timeit(f2, number=10)
1.959099448888992

timeit.timeit(f3, number=10)
0.48741375999998127
```

**Conculsion:**
**fastest** method is isnumeric(), **slowest** is regular expression method.

=========================================

**Edit:**
As @set92 commented, isnumeric() works for integer only. So the fastest applicable function is pd.to_numeric() to have a universal solutions works for any type of numerical values.

It is possible to define a isfloat() function in python; but it will be slower than internal functions, especially for big DataFrames.

```
tmp=['4.0','4','4.5','1','test']*200000
df=pd.DataFrame(data=tmp,columns=['num'])


def f1():
    df[pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce').isnull()]

def f2():
    df[df['num'].apply(lambda x: not isfloat(x))] 

def f3():
    df[~df.num.str.match('^\-?(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)$')]


print('to_numeric:',timeit.timeit(f1, number=10))
print('isfloat:',timeit.timeit(f2, number=10))
print('regular exp:',timeit.timeit(f3, number=10))
```

Results:

```
to_numeric: 8.303612694763615
isfloat: 9.972200270603594
regular exp: 11.420604273894583
```

Comment: It shouldn't work, df['num'] is float, and isnumeric() and isdigit() only works for integers. I was searching some function but seems the only solution available is create a function ```def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False``` and with it change your solution to ```df['num'].loc[df['num'].apply(lambda x: not isfloat(x))]```

Comment: but pd.to_numeric() works without any problem. It's an internal function and fast. No need to define a function!

Comment: with pd.to_numeric I got an error the strings (```ValueError: Unable to parse string "Unrated" at position 32```). If you want to try the dataset was ramen ratings of [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/ramen-ratings). But the problem was that the feature Stars has float numbers and 3 cells with "Unrated", so I couldn't find a one-line to apply it and find how many rows were not number.

Comment: you should use `pd.to_numeric(... ,errors='coerce')` to skip errors

Comment: only `df[pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce').isnull()]` could match floats

Answer (score 4):

I used

```
df = df[df['num'].apply(lambda x: type(x) == str)]
```

and now df is

```
  N-D     num unit
4  Q5  sum(d)   UD
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are strings, you can filter based on a regular expression match of a floating point number.

```
df[~df.num.str.match('^\-?(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)$')]

  N-D     num unit
4  Q5  sum(d)   UD
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to detect non-numeric values in the column of pandas DataFrame, here is one.

```
df[~df['num'].map(lambda x:x.isnumeric())]
```