# How to display non numeric values from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data Frame:

```
Measure|Value
-------|----
A|1000
B|1000/
C|1000*
D|10
E|1000 0
F|1000
G|5..
H|2
I|w
K|288
L|
M|565
```

Results:

```
Measure|Value
-------|----
B|1000/
C|1000*
D|10
E|1000 0
G|5..
I|w
L|
```

In SQL I use query:

```
select Measure,Value from dataframe where isnumeric(value)=0 or patindex('%[^0-9.-]%', value)!=0
```

How to display non numeric values from data frame in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771133/finding-non-numeric-rows-in-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, I have checked, code:  data.applymap(np.isreal) applies for all column, but I want to apply to Value column only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) with `~` to invert the boolean mask:

```
In[6]: df.loc[~df['Value'].astype(str).str.isdigit()]

Out[6]:
   Measure   Value
1        B   1000/
2        C   1000*
4        E  1000 0
6        G     5..
8        I       w
10       L     NaN
```

If the `dtype` of the column is already `str` then you don't need the `astype(str)` call