# Python rounding columns to two floating points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the question: Round the profit and sales columns to two floating points. Superstore is a dataset I have imported as a pandas dataframe.
The code I have written is:

```
superstore = superstore[superstore['Sales'] != ' 16GB']

#part 4
superstore['Profit'] = superstore['Profit'].round(2)
superstore['Sales'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
#sales = float(superstore['Sales'])
numeric_filter = filter(str.isdigit, superstore['Sales'])
#sales = float(raw_input('Sales'))

superstore['Sales'] = superstore['Sales'].round(2)
```

I keep getting the error, "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" and I am unsure of how to fix this. The error is on the line, "superstore['Sales'] = superstore['Sales'].round(2)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771133/finding-non-numeric-rows-in-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
superstore['Sales'].astype(float).round(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your column has some values that could not be cast to float:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Sales':[2.53,78.3,54,'ali']})
df['Sales'].round(2)
```

Which produces:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

In order to find non-float values, try:

```
for i in df['Sales']:
    print(float(i))
```